# Webstorm разворачивание конструкций javascript jquery и тд?

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

Понемногу перехожу с `Sublime Text` на `Webstorm`, пытаюсь разобраться в нем...

Подскажите как можно быстро разворачивать в нем конструкции типа `switch`, `if` и прочих как в плагине `Sublime - Java​Script Completions`. Например пишем `switch + enter` в итоге:

```
switch (expression) {
    case label_1:
// statements_1
        break;
    default:
// statements_def
        break;
}
```

или при помощи другого плагина `jQuery`, пишем ready в итоге:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

Может есть плагин какой?

Comment: можешь написать `live templates` с шаблонами и ключевыми словами как тебе удобно. Например цикл создается вводя `itar + TAB`. Все готовые можешь посмотреть там

Comment: а готовых вариантов нету, чтоб не прибегать к ручному вводу всех конструкций?

Comment: IDE настраивается как говорится `под себя`. Ты можешь единожды её настроить, затем экспортировать все настройки и хранить где угодно. И в последующие разы только вставлять свой пакет настроек, и у тебя будет все как и всегда. Какие то вещи есть, каких то нет. Придется делать самому :)